# The usage of Kolomogorov-Smirnov statistic in predictive modelling

Tags: predictive-models, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic... I read in wiki that it is used to compare a sample distribution  with reference.

However, I've interned in a company which was supposed to do predictive modeling and they keep talking about *KS for a model*. What were they talking about?

Comment: What is wrong with the explanation on wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_Smirnov?  Is the question "what is the KS statistic" or "how can it be used in the predictive modelling context"?  If the latter we probably need more information.

Comment: Why don't you ask your colleagues?!

Comment: Please try to keep your questions in a more serious tone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When measuring predictive models of binary outcome, KS refers to the distance between distributions of positive outcome and negative outcome. Apparently higher KS means more separation of positive vs negative, i.e. better prediction.